# PHP: Insert multiple values in a database field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that my question is against ALL principles and regulations. But I need to store multiple values in one field.

Because I have an amount of products who all have different amounts of price values and link values. So every product know a certain amount of prices but every price is assigned to one product.
But as I said, every product have a different amount of price values (Price comparison).

My problem now is because every product has a different amount of price and link values I don't know how many rows of prices I need. One solutions could be rows like: price1, price2, price3 and so on. But I don't know how many prices one product have and it would be more space dissipation then saving multiple values in one field.

Does anybody has an idea how I can save multiple values in one field or has anybody a better idea then that?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: create a master table with fields `productname` and `productid`..another table with `productprice` and `productid`. So you can add as many prices as you want

Comment: Make a price table with a product id field. You can have a one to many relationship between product and price then.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Read about database normalization. That shows how to structure the database the way you need it. There is no need to store multiple values in a single cell, though that certainly would be possible, for example by means of serialization. But don't do that. Stick with the proven and working relational database model.

Comment: But then I have still my problem. Because I have a variable amount of prices. And how can I tell my productname and productid table that this this and this price row should be assigned to this product?

Comment: @Jan Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820015/how-do-you-teach-database-normalization